# Joining Based on Count

Tags: sql

My table is formatted as:

```
City       Amount     Name
New York   10,000     Joe
Boston     10,000     Tom
New York   15,000     Jev
```

I am looking for a query that will return the names of pairs of people who have at least 25 cities in common together and the exact number of common cities. My output needs to be in the form of:

City, Name1, Name2, Count(*)

I've tried a various number of variations of the below:

```
select t1.city, t1.name, t2.name, count(*) from T t1 join T t2
on t1.city = t2.city 
where count(*) > 25
```

but I am having no luck. Please advise.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (sql server, mysql, oracle, postgres)?

Comment: I am using SQL as my RDBMS

Comment: Using where with aggregation function can’t work, having is for that

Comment: @CyberK10 "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database"

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  You need a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select t1.city, t1.name, t2.name, count(*)
from T t1 join
     T t2
     on t1.city = t2.city 
group by t1.city, t1.name, t2.name
having count(*) > 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use window functions to get after what you want:

```
SELECT city, name1, name2, count_of_cities
(
  select t1.city, t1.name as Name1, t2.name as Name2, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.name, t2.name) as count_of_cities 
  from T t1 join T t2
    on t1.city = t2.city 
) dt
WHERE dt.count_of_cities > 25;
```